# Metabase Connection With SQL Server (Linux Container) getting timeout error

Tags: sql-server, metabase

I am trying to connect Metabase with SQL Server.

[SQL Server is linux docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017) with SA user and password, and port as 1433.

in Metabase database configuration page i am using below information:-

Host : 152.XXX.XXX.XX (ip address of database server).

Port : 1433

User Name: SA

Password : mypassword

Database : mydatabase

Github has already open [issue](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/6056) , is there any workaround?
tried with version 0.25.2 and 0,30.x, same issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your server listens on 1433 port?

Comment: yes, i have connected SQL Developer UI with same connection details.